# How ViewsLifetime work in sharepoint search?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

Just wanted to know how Viewslifetime works in sharepoint pages. Need to know it update the view count on daily basis of sharepoint pages or it runs daily but displays once every 15 days in sharepoint pages. Can you just let me know how it works according to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

ViewsLifetime means the sum of all the views since the document was created.

The value ViewsLifetime is updated by the timer job Usage Analytics which run once a day (usually at 1am) to analyse all raw usage logs captured by the timer job Usage Data Import (run once every 5 mins).

References:

[Usage Analytics (ViewsLifetime)](http://anthonynhn.blogspot.com/2017/12/sharepoint-2013-usage-analytics.html)

[SharePointProblems - How to interpret SharePoint’s view count managed properties (like “ViewsLast1Days”)?](https://www.koskila.net/how-to-interpret-sharepoints-view-count-managed-properties-like-viewslast1days/)